# Does the same .NET dll compile to the same runtime assembly code on different machines?

Tags: .net, assembly, hook

I wonder if I can hook class methods using standart JMP hooks. If hook signatures are the same on different machines like for standart compiled PE files?

**UPDATE**: I mean CIL to machine code compilation. I need to understand if this machine code are the same for one .NET DLL loaded on three different OS with the same architecture (like Windows 7/8/10 x64).

**UPDATE2**: Let me explain in a little more detail what I need to get as a result.

I have third party .NET DLL with class "A", which has method "M" and variable "V". Method "M" just show the value of "V" variable.

My *goal* is to change variable "V" from inside method "M". So, when method "V" is called, it will show a new data.

One of the usual methods which I perform for saying C++ is to get function signature (first function bytes), find them in memory and setting hook which JMPs to my DLL. However, because of JIT here, it will generate different machine code. So I can not create function signature, thus I cant find it in memory and can not set hook.

How does hook here?

Comment: Which compilation are you talking about? .NET to CIL or CIL to machine code? And what do you mean by "hook signature"?

Comment: The question has been updated according to your questions.

Comment: Why are you asking? Smart JIT compilers take advantage of the machine's/CPU's features so the JIT will generate different assembly code for different machines to take advantage of them.

Comment: I'm  asking, because I need to hook some class methods. In case if function signature (like first N bytes of method) are not the same, so I need to use symbols to get the start of the function.

Comment: Obviously the ARM and x64 machine code will be completely different, is anything non-x64 a concern?

Comment: @harold, what is about the same architecture, but different OS, like Windows 7/8/10 x64?

Comment: But also don't forget that the JIT is free to do call optimizations as well, e.g. tail-call optimizations, inlining methods and now there is also multi-tiered JIT in .net core which can re-generate some JITed code if it thinks there will be a preformance win. this may be problematic for hooking that you do AFTER JITing

Comment: @MartinUllrich, thank you for your answer. Does this mean I need to hook JIT'ing process? Like waiting for code generation for interesting class method, then setting hook?

Comment: Thanks for the update. As others have pointed out, the machine code will be different. Even on the same OS but with different runtimes (e.g. framework version X vs Y). Also, the result of the JIT is transient. It will stay in memory as long as the JIT thinks it's worth keeping it, then it will be regenerated. Do you intend to hook `compileMethod`? Maybe a little more context will help in answering

Comment: @MargaretBloom thanks for answering my question. I've added more details in the question.

Comment: Why does this patching have to be done at runtime? Can you not decompile the assembly with the method you want to change and, well, change it?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, this DLL is a part of service. Stopping service might have unexpected consequences. Do you mean change C# code, compile it to the new DLL and replace the original one?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone is interested in the answer.

I took a .NET application with loaded .NET dll inside. Then found an interested function and took its assembly code after JITting. The assembly code was taken from Windows 7/10/2012 (x64). I ended up comparing all three copied functions from different systems.

I found that, the code was almost completely the same, even using the same prologue, registers, number of instructions, etc.

The difference was in two things:

1. Absolute addresses (this is obvious, like "call ")
2. One optimized instruction in the middle of the function.

Windows 10/2012 used this:

```
mov rdx,0000006454DE0FB0
mov rdx,[rdx]
```

whereas Windows 7 used this:

```
mov rdx,[12AFF340]
```

Thus it seems that runtime assembly code for one .NET dll is not very different on the same architecture. We also can find function in memory using its signature and even can call class methods knowing that registers at certain instruction will be used for that class member.

Comment: You only tested one particular case.  You can't rule out differences for functions where BMI2 shift instructions like `shlx` would have been useful for example, and maybe get used on one computer but not on an older computer that doesn't have them.  If it doesn't need to be bulletproof and totally future-proof (against new .NET versions that optimize better / differently), and only work for some known set of functions you've tested, then sure, go for it.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I agree. Honestly, it requires many additional tests. We need to look at each situation separately, depending on the task.